# ggplot - use numeric values to fill stacked bar charts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to build a stacked bar chart, providing in the field  `fill` numeric values and not categories.

This is my graph so far:

[image: graph]

In the [ggplot example](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar.html) for the stacked bar chart, the field `fill` correspond to the column `cut` of the `diamonds` dataset.
This column correspond to :

```
> class(diamonds$cut)
[1] "ordered" "factor"
```

Therefore, I think that the frequence of the different terms

```
> head(diamonds$cut)
[1] Ideal     Premium   Good      Premium   Good      Very Good
Levels: Fair < Good < Very Good < Premium < Ideal
```

is calculated and used to fill the bars.

[image: ggplot stacked bar chart]

In my case I have each value of the bar displayed on X (`tot` in my dataframe) formed by two type of value: `up`, `down`. These correspond to columns in my dataframe:

```
> head(cyt.4)
                                                             COG tot up down
1                           [C] Energy production and conversion  17 16    1
2 [D] Cell cycle control, cell division, chromosome partitioning   0  0    0
3                        [E] Amino acid transport and metabolism  34 30    4
4                        [F] Nucleotide transport and metabolism  11  9    2
5                      [G] Carbohydrate transport and metabolism  13  9    4
6                          [H] Coenzyme transport and metabolism   3  3    0
```

For example a bar that has a X (`tot`) value of 10, can be divided in `up`=7, `down`=3. Now, let's say I assign red to `up` and green to `down`, I would like that my bar would be filled for the 70% (7 out of 10) red and for the 30% green (3 out of 10).

I was struggling with that for days and I did not get any valid results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert your data from "wide" to "long" format, for example using the `reshape` package. Then things get easier in `ggplot`. The restructured dataframe contains `variable` with values "down" and "up". This can be given to `fill=` as an ordered or unordered factor.

Below is a minimal example, that mimics your data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

x <- c(14,11,9,17)
dfr <- data.frame(COG=letters[1:4], down=1:4, up=x-1:4, tot=x)
dfr <- melt(dfr[,-4], idvar="COG")

ggplot(dfr, aes(x=COG, y=value, fill=factor(variable))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("green3","red3"))
```

[image]

Cheers!

Edit: If the levels get mixed up in your dataset, then it's because `factor` creates factor levels in the order as it finds it. To change the order either reorder your dataset (as I did) and let `melt` take care of it, or leave it and use `ordered` to make the factor follow an order as you specify.

Comment: This is great, but I cannot have it working. Se my comands below:      `> colnames(cyt.4)
[1] "cyt.4"    "variable" "value"   
> ggplot(cyt.4, aes(x=COG, y=value, fill=factor(variable))) +
+   geom_bar(stat="identity") +
+   coord_flip() +
+   scale_fill_manual(values=c("green3","red3"))
Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:COG`.                                                     I think that I get this error because the vector `factor(variable)` does not have the same length of `COG`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Stupid me! I had an error in column names! Your hint was great! Thanks!