# Faceted stacked density plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say my data is as follows :

```
set.seed(123)
a <- sample(1:10, 50, replace = TRUE)
b <- sample(1:10, 50, replace = TRUE)
c <- sample(3:10, 50, replace = TRUE)
data <- data.frame(a,b,c)

data$AA <- cut(data$a, breaks = c(0,3,6,10), right = TRUE,
               labels = c ("typ 1", "typ 2", "typ 3"))
data$BB <- cut(data$b, breaks = c(0,3,6,10), right = TRUE,
               labels = c ("typ 1", "typ 2", "typ 3"))
data$CC <- cut(data$c, breaks = c(0,3,6,10), right = TRUE,
               labels = c ("typ 1", "typ 2", "typ 3"))
```

I am wanting to plot the stacked density distribution of typ1,2,3 for `a,b` and `c` (column 1:3)

The desired output is similiar to

[image]

As suggested by @MrFlick, I need to convert to long format.

My new table should look like this:

[image]

I have tried using

```
data$a <- as.factor(data$a)
data$b <- as.factor(data$b)
data$c <- as.factor(data$c)
data.2 <- melt(data[,-7], idvar=c("a", "b", "c"))
```

But this output the following message

```
Using a, b, c, AA, BB, CC as id variables
```

Comment: You need to convert your data from "wide" format to "long" format. I think this question pretty much does the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079137/ggplot-use-numeric-values-to-fill-stacked-bar-charts

Comment: ok thanks for the link, so I need to melt the data using reshape

Comment: You can use `reshape()` (from base R) or `melt()` (from reshape2) or `gather()` (from tidyr). There are lots of options out there if you search for "reshape wide to long"